# assign stat|grep|awk to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, awk, grep

I have a file of filenames, and I need to be able to get the size of these files using bash.
I have the following script which does that, but It prints the filename and the size on different lines, i'd prefer it to do it all on one line if possible.

```
#!/bin/sh
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
    name=$line
    vars=(`echo $name | tr '.' ' '`)
    echo $name
    stat -x $name | grep Size: | awk '{ print $2 }'
done < "$filename"
```

I'd love to have it of the form:

```
filename: $size
```

How can I do this?
(I am using OSX hence the slightly odd version of stat.)

Comment: Show us sample contents of "filename", sample output of "stat -x $name" on the contents of "filename" you care about, and the final output you want the script to produce given that sample input.

Comment: where do you use the result of your `vars=( ... )`. Does that need to be in your question? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `-n` to the `echo` to prevent a trailing newline from being added. So change

```
echo $name
```

to

```
echo -n $name
```

and to add the `:` separator between the file name and file size

```
echo -n ${name}": "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $name: $(stat -x $name | sed -n '/^Size:/s///p')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I can't do the $( stuff | stuff). It gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
while read f
do
  echo "${f} : $(stat -L -c %s ${f})"
done < "${filename}"
```

Comment: I was checking [the bsd man page for stat](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat) -- try `stat -f "%N: %z" "$f"`. The while loop can be shortened with `xargs stat -f "%N: %z" < "$filename"`

Comment: @KevinShaffer In that case, `stat -L -f %z ${f}`... Or see comment by @glennjackman for an alternative w/o the `echo` and/or loop...